# Do you know how to reduce the gap between week and date in fsCalendar and between date and date?

Tags: swift, fscalendar

I am creating a calendar using fsCalender.
There are no other issues, but I can't figure out how to reduce that interval.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdXLn.png)

Does anyone know of a good way?

this is my code :

```
func initCalender() {
    calenderView.delegate = self
    calenderView.dataSource = self
    calenderView.locale = Locale(identifier: "en-US")
    calenderView.appearance.caseOptions = FSCalendarCaseOptions.weekdayUsesSingleUpperCase
    
    calenderView.today = nil // 오늘 선택 없애기
    calenderView.scrollEnabled = false // 캘린더 스크롤
    calenderView.headerHeight = 0 // 헤더 없애기
    calenderView.placeholderType = .none
    calenderView.weekdayHeight = 15
    calenderView.scope = .month
    //self.calenderView.appearance.subtitleOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    calenderView.register(DIYCalendarCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    
    calenderView.appearance.weekdayFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13)
    calenderView.appearance.titleFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)
    
    updateHeader()

}
```

Comment: you need to just decrease calendar height according to your need then it will adjust spacing according to height of calendar. More height of calendar more space between cells.